# New to Python, trying to do print statements. College textbook is super short not being helpful

Tags: python

Ok so I'm working on a problem in my python class. I've gotten most of it figured out aside from print statements. I assigned the arguements correctly (I think) and am just trying to get the text to print correctly on the terminal side. What am I doing wrong here?

[here is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pedl.png)

[is the example that mine is supposed to look similar to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARHy.png)

Comment: Please include code and results as text in the question, not as images.

Comment: Please note that [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] as text.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  We expect you to do appropriate research before posting a question here.  Also, off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

you could use f string print statements too like this:

```
print(f"distance in knots is: {distance_in_knots}")
```